# Ajax only effects 1 button, instead of all buttons

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I want to set up my index.php so that when the like button is clicked, ajax is used to go to liked_button.php and change the look of the button to 'Liked'. This works, for one button, the first button. It doesn't work for all the other buttons on the page. Liking another button other than the first button, makes it appear as if the first button was liked. So my question is, how do I apply this ajax code to 'ALL' of the like buttons on index.php?

Here is the index.php :

```
<!doctype html>
<head>

<?php
    include('header.php');
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
         $.ajax({url:"liked_button.php",success:function(result){
             $("#like_system").html(result);
            }});
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<body>

<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("No SQLI");
    mysqli_select_db($conn, "sample") or die ("No DB");

$sqli = "SELECT * FROM `photos` ORDER BY `id` DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqli) or die ("No query");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))    

{
$username = $row['username'];
$title = $row['title'];
$description = $row['description'];
$image_name = $row['image_name'];
$image_id = $row['image_id'];
$random_directory = $row['random_direc'];
$date = date('Y-m-d');

$image_info = "http://localhost/splindr_2.0/photos/$random_directory/$image_id";

echo "<div id=contentWrapper'>
          <div id='photo'>
              <div id='actual_image'>
                 <img src='$image_info'>
              </div>          
              <div id='like_system'><button type='button' class='button'  name='button'>Like</button></div>     
                    <div id='info_wrapper'>
                       <div id='info_header'>Title: $title &nbsp By: $username &nbsp  Date: $date</div>
                           <div id='description'>$description</div>
                    </div>
          </div>
      </div>";//end contentWrapper

}

?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the liked_button.php :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="liked_button.css">
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" id="button_pressed">Liked</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ***Liking another button other than the first button, makes it appear as if the first button was liked*** so each button should have different apprearance of ***liked*** state?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the basic idea:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
         var t=$(this);
         $.ajax({url:"liked_button.php",success:function(result){
             t.replaceWith("<button type='button' id='button_pressed'>Liked</button>")
         }});
    });
});
```

Your other issue is that you use id overly much.  Replace all looped uses of `id` (including in the code I gave you) with `class`, or else your code won't work.

Comment: Basically, yeah.  For example, `id="info_wrapper"` will only return the first result, because id is supposed to be unique.

Comment: So if I wanted to increment .total_likes by 1 everytime a .button is clicked, would this be the appropriate js?                  `<script>
function increase()  {
            var total_likes=document.getElementById("total_likes");
            total_likes.value++;
        }
</script>`

Comment: No, not quite.  You have to say `total_likes.value=parseInt(total_likes.value)+1`.

Comment: Okay I tried that, and it works for the first post again, but not for the others, which is weird now that I've changed everything to classes, from id's. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're using id's.  What I'd say is you have to pass the individual case to the increase function, so that on the button, you'd write `increase(this)` and then you could use jquery to say `$(t).next().val($(t).next().val())` or something.  I'd need more detailed code to say.  Also, you'd probably want a script for subtracting on unlike.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54664/discussion-between-ralston3-and-scelesto).

Answer (score 0):

HTML IDs (such as your `like_system`) must be unique. Your update selector is finding the first one every time.

Try something like:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  var clicked = $(this);

  $.ajax({url:"liked_button.php",success:function(result){
    clicked.closest('div').html(result);
  }});
});
```

And either remove the `like_system` ID, or replace it with a class if you need to style it, etc.